# HTML Textarea style scrollbar corner borders

Tags: html, css, webkit, textarea, scrollbar

I am trying to style the Textarea's resizer in the dark mode of my website so that it is not a white block in an otherwise dark website. As such, I tried to both use `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner` and `::-webkit-resizer`, although the first one leaves white corners (see screenshot), while the other one removes the characteristic two lines from the resizer. I know these changes will affect only Webkit and Blink based browsers, thus not [IE, older versions of Edge and Firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-resizer). Is there a way I can style `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner` to avoid having those white corners? I want to avoid adding custom wrappers with custom scrollbars as much as I can, as it would take me way longer and add unnecessary complexity.

[image: Example of resizer with white borders]

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: green;
}

textarea {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
  Hello
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  World
</textarea>
```

**Update**: To clarify, I still need the textareas to be resizable, I want to know if there is a way to remove the white top and left borders from the resizer without styling `::-webkit-resizer` which would mean using an SVG to have the two lines typical of the resizer, as in the image.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `textarea` can be resized, so the bottom right corner is resizing box.
You can remove it by setting the `resize` property of `textarea as` none;`

I think you can do like this.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: green;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #002200;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

textarea {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
  Hello
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  World
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I didn't expressily say this, but I need the textareas to still be resizable, but I want to avoid the resizer having that white background.